# Problems with a functions question.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Having a bit of trouble with a question:

The amount of bacteria within a tub of yogourt at time $t$ is $500e^{0.2t}$.

(a) How many bacteria cells will be in the tub at time
t = 50? t = 100?

(b) Determine the time $t$ at which the total amount of bacteria
cells will be $100,000$.

For a) I turned it into the equation $y=500e^{0.2t}$ and then subbed in the $t$ values and solved the question, great.

However for b), I used $100,000=500e^{0.2t}$ and for the time I got $t=163$ which doesn't make sense because for a) with $t=50$ I got $11$ million bacteria. So it obviously doesn't make sense that it would take longer to get $100,000$ bacteria than $11$ million. What did I do wrong? Thanks!
P.S New to this, if I did anything wrong just lemme know, thanks!

**Edit:** Figured it out sorta, now I have $100,000=610.7^t$. I know there's a way, but how do I get the $t$ out of being squared. Could I just square root the variable and the $100,000$ on the other side. Though that doesn't seem possible to me. If anyone could help out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  If you edit your post to show us your calculations, it will help us determine what mistakes you are making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) you simply plug in your values for $t$.

For b) You have to solve 
$$100000=500e^{0.2t}$$
Now devide by $500$ 
$$200=e^{0.2t}$$
Now simply introduce the natural logarithm to the base $e$ on both sides
$$\ln(200)=0.2t$$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Excellent! I knew there was some way to get rid of the exponent, but forget. Thanks a lot friend!